# I am getting the sigabert thread in my main repeatedly

Tags: swift

What it shows is something like shown:

```
nt main(int argc, char * argv[]) {     
    @autoreleasepool {         
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    } 
}
```

I have tried to edit breakpoints also but it did't work for me.